# Sitecore upgrade to 9.1 not indexing solr fields

Tags: solr, content-search, upgrade

I have upgraded my Sitecore instance from `Sitecore.NET 8.2 (rev. 161221)` to `Sitecore 9.1 update-1`. while running migration I ran into the issue where I had `<indexAllFields>` in the following config and I had to remove it cause it was causing the below exception. After migration lot of fields are missing from the index such as summary_t etc which were there before. Tried rebuilding the indexes multiple times.

**Exception:**

```
Could not find property 'indexAllFields' on object of type: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration
```

**Configuration:**

```
  <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
      <sitecore>
        <contentSearch>
          <configuration>
            <indexes>
              <index id="sitecore_master_index">
                <configuration>
                  <patch:attribute name="ref">contentSearch/indexConfigurations/extendedSolrIndexConfiguration</patch:attribute>
                </configuration>
              </index>
              <index id="sitecore_web_index">
                <configuration>
                  <patch:attribute name="ref">contentSearch/indexConfigurations/extendedSolrIndexConfiguration</patch:attribute>
                </configuration>
              </index>
            </indexes>
          </configuration>
          <indexConfigurations>
            <extendedSolrIndexConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
        <indexAllFields>true</indexAllFields> //removed this after sitecore upgrade
              <initializeOnAdd>false</initializeOnAdd>
              <fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrFieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                <typeMatches hint="raw:AddTypeMatch">
                  <typeMatch type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Guid]" typeName="guidCollection" fieldNameFormat="{0}_sm" multiValued="true" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                  <typeMatch type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]" typeName="stringCollection" fieldNameFormat="{0}_sm" multiValued="true" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                  <typeMatch type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]" typeName="intCollection" fieldNameFormat="{0}_im" multiValued="true" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                  <typeMatch type="System.Guid" typeName="guid" fieldNameFormat="{0}_s" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                  <typeMatch type="Sitecore.Data.ID, Sitecore.Kernel" typeName="id" fieldNameFormat="{0}_s" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                  <typeMatch type="Sitecore.Data.ShortID, Sitecore.Kernel" typeName="shortid" fieldNameFormat="{0}_s" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                  <typeMatch type="System.String" typeName="text" fieldNameFormat="{0}_t" cultureFormat="_{1}" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                  <typeMatch type="System.String" typeName="string" fieldNameFormat="{0}_s" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                  <typeMatch type="System.Int32" typeName="int" fieldNameFormat="{0}_tl" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                  <typeMatch type="System.Boolean" typeName="bool" fieldNameFormat="{0}_b" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                  <typeMatch type="System.DateTime" typeName="datetime" fieldNameFormat="{0}_tdt" format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.FFF'Z'" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                  <typeMatch type="System.Int64" typeName="long" fieldNameFormat="{0}_tl" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                  <typeMatch type="System.Single" typeName="float" fieldNameFormat="{0}_tf" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                  <typeMatch type="System.Double" typeName="double" fieldNameFormat="{0}_td" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                  <typeMatch type="System.String[]" typeName="stringArray" fieldNameFormat="{0}_sm" multiValued="true" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                  <typeMatch type="System.Int32[]" typeName="intArray" fieldNameFormat="{0}_im" multiValued="true" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                  <typeMatch type="System.DateTime[]" typeName="datetimeArray" fieldNameFormat="{0}_dtm" multiValued="true" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                  <typeMatch type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.DateTime]" typeName="datetimeCollection" fieldNameFormat="{0}_dtm" multiValued="true" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
                </typeMatches>
                <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName" >
                  <field fieldName="__created_by" returnType="string" />
                  <field fieldName="__smallcreateddate" returnType="datetime" format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'" />
                  <field fieldName="__smallupdateddate" returnType="datetime" format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'" />
                  <field fieldName="__workflow_state" returnType="string" />
                  <field fieldName="extension" returnType="text" />
                  <field fieldName="title" returnType="text" />
                  <field fieldName="metadata_keywords" returnType="string" />
                  <field fieldName="newsarticle_tags" returnType="stringCollection" multiValued="true" />
                  <field fieldName="workflow_review_dates" returnType="datetimeCollection" multiValued="true"  />
                  <field fieldName="all_templates" returnType="string" />
                  <field fieldName="has_presentation" returnType="bool" />
                  <field fieldName="has_search_result_formatter" returnType="bool" />
                  <field fieldName="content_type" returnType="string"  />
                  <field fieldName="website_section" returnType="string" />
                </fieldNames>
                <!-- FIELD TYPE MAPPING
               <fieldTypes hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldTypeName">
                  <fieldType fieldTypeName="checkbox" returnType="bool" />
                  <fieldType fieldTypeName="date|datetime" returnType="datetime" />
                  <fieldType fieldTypeName="html|rich text|single-line text|multi-line text|text|memo|image|reference" returnType="text" />
                  <fieldType fieldTypeName="word document" returnType="text" />
                  <fieldType fieldTypeName="integer" returnType="long" />
                  <fieldType fieldTypeName="number" returnType="float" />
                  <fieldType fieldTypeName="icon|droplist|grouped droplist" returnType="string" />
                  <fieldType fieldTypeName="checklist|multilist|treelist|tree list|treelistex|tree list|multilist with search|treelist with search" returnType="stringCollection" />
                  <fieldType fieldTypeName="name lookup value list|name value list" returnType="stringCollection" />
                  <fieldType fieldTypeName="droplink|droptree|grouped droplink|tree" returnType="stringCollection" />
                </fieldTypes>
              </fieldMap>
              <documentOptions type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrDocumentBuilderOptions, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" >
                <exclude hint="list:AddExcludedTemplate">
                  <BucketFolderTemplateId>{ADB6CA4F-03EF-4F47-B9AC-9CE2BA53FF97}</BucketFolderTemplateId>
                </exclude>
                <!-- GLOBALLY EXCLUDE FIELDS FROM BEING INDEXED
                   This setting allows you to exclude fields from the index when the indexAllFields setting is set to true.
                -->
                <exclude hint="list:AddExcludedField">
                  <__Created>{25BED78C-4957-4165-998A-CA1B52F67497}</__Created>
                  <__DefaultWorkflow>{CA9B9F52-4FB0-4F87-A79F-24DEA62CDA65}</__DefaultWorkflow>
                  <__Lock>{001DD393-96C5-490B-924A-B0F25CD9EFD8}</__Lock>
                  <__LongDescription>{577F1689-7DE4-4AD2-A15F-7FDC1759285F}</__LongDescription>
                  <__Originator>{F6D8A61C-2F84-4401-BD24-52D2068172BC}</__Originator>
                  <__Owner>{52807595-0F8F-4B20-8D2A-CB71D28C6103}</__Owner>
                  <__ReadOnly>{9C6106EA-7A5A-48E2-8CAD-F0F693B1E2D4}</__ReadOnly>
                  <__Renderings>{F1A1FE9E-A60C-4DDB-A3A0-BB5B29FE732E}</__Renderings>
                  <__Revision>{8CDC337E-A112-42FB-BBB4-4143751E123F}</__Revision>
                  <__Security>{DEC8D2D5-E3CF-48B6-A653-8E69E2716641}</__Security>
                  <__ShortDescription>{9541E67D-CE8C-4225-803D-33F7F29F09EF}</__ShortDescription>
                  <__SortOrder>{BA3F86A2-4A1C-4D78-B63D-91C2779C1B5E}</__SortOrder>
                  <__Source>{1B86697D-60CA-4D80-83FB-7555A2E6CE1C}</__Source>
                  <__Updated>{D9CF14B1-FA16-4BA6-9288-E8A174D4D522}</__Updated>
                  <__UpdatedBy>{BADD9CF9-53E0-4D0C-BCC0-2D784C282F6A}</__UpdatedBy>
                  <__ValidFrom>{C8F93AFE-BFD4-4E8F-9C61-152559854661}</__ValidFrom>
                  <__Workflow>{A4F985D9-98B3-4B52-AAAF-4344F6E747C6}</__Workflow>
                  <ArchiveDate>{56C15C6D-FD5A-40CA-BB37-64CEEC6A9BD5}</ArchiveDate>
                  <ArchiveVersionDate>{1D99005E-65CA-45CA-9D9A-FD7016E23F1E}</ArchiveVersionDate>
                  <Boost>{93D1B217-B8F4-462E-BABF-68298C9CE667}</Boost>
                  <BucketParentReference>{9DAFCA1D-D618-4616-86B8-A8ACD6B28A63}</BucketParentReference>
                  <Cacheable>{3D08DB46-2267-41B0-BC52-BE69FD618633}</Cacheable>
                  <ContextMenu>{D3AE7222-425D-4B77-95D8-EE33AC2B6730}</ContextMenu>
                  <Controller>{4C9312A5-2E4E-42F8-AB6F-B8DB8B82BF22}</Controller>
                  <ControllerAction>{9FB734CC-8952-4072-A2D4-40F890E16F56}</ControllerAction>
                  <DefaultBucketQuery>{AC51462C-8A8D-493B-9492-34D1F26F20F1}</DefaultBucketQuery>
                  <DefaultView>{3607F9C7-DDA3-43C3-9720-39A7A5B3A4C3}</DefaultView>
                  <Editor>{D85DB4EC-FF89-4F9C-9E7C-A9E0654797FC}</Editor>
                  <Editors>{A0CB3965-8884-4C7A-8815-B6B2E5CED162}</Editors>
                  <EnabledViews>{F2DB8BA1-E477-41F5-8EF5-22EEFA8D2F6E}</EnabledViews>
                  <Facets>{21F74F6E-42D4-42A2-A4B4-4CEFBCFBD2BB}</Facets>
                  <HelpLink>{56776EDF-261C-4ABC-9FE7-70C618795239}</HelpLink>
                  <HideVersion>{B8F42732-9CB8-478D-AE95-07E25345FB0F}</HideVersion>
                  <Icon>{06D5295C-ED2F-4A54-9BF2-26228D113318}</Icon>
                  <Masters>{1172F251-DAD4-4EFB-A329-0C63500E4F1E}</Masters>
                  <NeverPublish>{9135200A-5626-4DD8-AB9D-D665B8C11748}</NeverPublish>
                  <PersistentFilter>{C7815F60-96E1-40CB-BB06-B5F833F73B61}</PersistentFilter>
                  <Preview>{41C6CC0E-389F-4D51-9990-FE35417B6666}</Preview>
                  <Publish>{86FE4F77-4D9A-4EC3-9ED9-263D03BD1965}</Publish>
                  <ReminderDate>{ABE5D54C-59D7-41E6-8D3F-C1A3E4EC9B9E}</ReminderDate>
                  <ReminderText>{BB6C8540-118E-4C49-9157-830576D7345A}</ReminderText>
                  <Renderers>{B03569B1-1534-43F2-8C83-BD064B7D782C}</Renderers>
                  <Ribbon>{0C894AAB-962B-4A84-B923-CB24B05E60D2}</Ribbon>
                  <Skin>{079AFCFE-8ACA-4863-BDA7-07893541E2F5}</Skin>
                  <Style>{A791F095-2521-4B4D-BEF9-21DDA221F608}</Style>
                  <SubItemSorting>{6FD695E7-7F6D-4CA5-8B49-A829E5950AE9}</SubItemSorting>
                  <SuppressedValidationRules>{F47C0D78-61F9-479C-96DF-1159727D32C6}</SuppressedValidationRules>
                  <UnPublish>{7EAD6FD6-6CF1-4ACA-AC6B-B200E7BAFE88}</UnPublish>
                  <UserAgent>{4E678FC0-8D35-4AB7-BB49-156F33C8B955}</UserAgent>
                  <ValidTo>{4C346442-E859-4EFD-89B2-44AEDF467D21}</ValidTo>
                  <VaryByData>{8B6D532B-6128-4486-A044-CA06D90948BA}</VaryByData>
                  <VaryByDevice>{C98CF969-BA71-42DA-833D-B3FC1368BA27}</VaryByDevice>
                  <VaryByLogin>{8D9232B0-613F-440B-A2FA-DCDD80FBD33E}</VaryByLogin>
                  <VaryByParam>{3AD2506A-DC39-4B1E-959F-9D524ADDBF50}</VaryByParam>
                  <VaryByQueryString>{1084D3D2-0457-456A-ABBC-EB4CC0966072}</VaryByQueryString>
                  <VaryByUser>{0E54A8DC-72AD-4372-A7C7-BB4773FAD44D}</VaryByUser>
                  <VaryByIndex>{F3E7E552-D7C8-469B-A150-69E4E14AB35C}</VaryByIndex>
                </exclude>
                <!-- REMOVE INBUILT SITECORE FIELDS
                   This allows you to store a field in different ways in the index. You may want to store a field as Analyzed and Not Analyze
                -->
                <fields hint="raw:AddExcludedSpecialField">
                  <remove type="both">AllTemplates</remove>
                  <remove type="both">Created</remove>
                  <remove type="both">Editor</remove>
                  <remove type="both">Hidden</remove>
                  <remove type="both">Icon</remove>
                  <remove type="both">Links</remove>
                  <remove type="both">Updated</remove>
                </fields>
               <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
                  <field fieldName="__smallcreateddate" returnType="string">Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.CreatedDate,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
                  <field fieldName="__smallupdateddate" returnType="string">Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.UpdatedDate,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
                  <field type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.MediaItemContentExtractor,Sitecore.ContentSearch" fieldName="_content" returnType="string">
                    <mediaIndexing ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/mediaIndexing" />
                  </field>
                  <field fieldName="calculateddimension" returnType="stringCollection">Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.CalculatedDimension,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
                  <field fieldName="culture" returnType="string">Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.Culture,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
                  <field fieldName="haschildren" returnType="bool">Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.HasChildren,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
                  <field fieldName="istemplate" returnType="bool">Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.IsTemplate,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
                  <field fieldName="lock" returnType="bool">Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.IsLocked,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
                  <field fieldName="parsedcreatedby" returnType="string">Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.ParsedCreatedBy,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
                  <field fieldName="parsedupdatedby" returnType="string">Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.ParsedUpdatedBy,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
                  <field fieldName="parsedlanguage" returnType="string">Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.ParsedLanguage,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
                  <field fieldName="site" returnType="stringCollection">Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.Site,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
                  <field fieldName="sizerange" returnType="string">Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.FileSizeGrouping,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
                  <field fieldName="version" returnType="intCollection">Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.StoreVersionTermVector,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
                  <field fieldName="isbucket_text" returnType="string">Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.IsBucket,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
                  <field fieldName="__lock" returnType="string">Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.ParsedLockOwner,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
                  <field fieldName="metadata_keywords" returnType="stringCollection" >Sitecore.Feature.Metadata.Infrastructure.Fields.KeywordsComputedField, Sitecore.Feature.Metadata</field>
                  <field fieldName="newsarticle_tags" returnType="stringCollection" multiValued="true" >Sitecore.Feature.News.Indexing.NewsTagsComputedField, Sitecore.Feature.News</field>
                  <field fieldName="workflow_review_dates" returnType="datetimeCollection" multiValued="true" >Sitecore.Feature.Workflow.Infrastructure.Indexing.ReviewDateRemindersComputedField, Sitecore.Feature.Workflow</field>
                  <field fieldName="has_presentation" returnType="boolean" >Sitecore.Foundation.Indexing.Infrastructure.Fields.HasPresentationComputedField, Sitecore.Foundation.Indexing</field>
                  <field fieldName="all_templates" returnType="stringColection" >Sitecore.Foundation.Indexing.Infrastructure.Fields.AllTemplatesComputedField, Sitecore.Foundation.Indexing</field>
                  <field fieldName="has_search_result_formatter" returnType="boolean" >Sitecore.Foundation.Indexing.Infrastructure.Fields.HasSearchResultFormatterComputedField, Sitecore.Foundation.Indexing</field>
                  <field fieldName="content_type" returnType="stringCollection" >Sitecore.Foundation.Indexing.Infrastructure.Fields.ContentTypeComputedField, Sitecore.Foundation.Indexing</field>
                  <field fieldName="local_datasource_content" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" >Sitecore.Foundation.LocalDatasource.Infrastructure.Indexing.LocalDatasourceContentField, Sitecore.Foundation.LocalDatasource</field>
                  <field fieldName="website_section" returnType="string">Sitecore.Unitywater.Website.Infrastructure.Fields.WebsiteSectionComputedField, Sitecore.Unitywater.Website</field>
                  <field fieldName="full_content" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED">Sitecore.Foundation.Indexing.Infrastructure.Fields.HtmlCrawledField, Sitecore.Foundation.Indexing</field>
                </fields>
              </documentOptions>
              <mediaIndexing hint="skip">
                <mimeTypes>
                  <excludes>
                    <mimeType>*</mimeType>
                  </excludes>
                  <includes>
                    <mimeType>application/pdf</mimeType>
                    <mimeType type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.MediaItemHtmlTextExtractor, Sitecore.ContentSearch">text/html</mimeType>
                    <mimeType>text/plain</mimeType>
                  </includes>
                </mimeTypes>
              </mediaIndexing>
              <!-- VIRTUAL FIELDS
                   Virtual fields can be used to translate a field query into a different query.
                -->
              <virtualFields type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.VirtualFieldProcessorMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                <processors hint="raw:AddFromConfiguration">
                  <add type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.VirtualFields.DateRangeFieldProcessor, Sitecore.ContentSearch" fieldName="daterange" />
                  <add type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.VirtualFields.LatestVersionFieldProcessor, Sitecore.ContentSearch" fieldName="_lastestversion" />
                  <add type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.VirtualFields.UpdatedDateRangeFieldProcessor, Sitecore.ContentSearch" fieldName="updateddaterange" />
                  <add type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.VirtualFields.UniqueIdFieldProcessor, Sitecore.ContentSearch" fieldName="_url" />
                  <add type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.VirtualFields.FullPathFieldProcessor, Sitecore.ContentSearch" fieldName="_fullpath" />
                  <add type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.VirtualFields.CreatedByFieldProcessor, Sitecore.ContentSearch" fieldName="parsedcreatedby_s" />
                  <add type="Sitecore.ItemWebApi.VirtualFields.UpdatedIntervalFieldProcessor, Sitecore.Speak.ItemWebApi" fieldName="updatedinterval"  />
                </processors>
              </virtualFields>
              <!-- SITECORE FIELDTYPE MAP
                   This maps a field type by name to a Strongly Typed Implementation of the field type e.g. html maps to HTMLField
                -->
              <fieldReaders type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.FieldReaderMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                <param desc="id">defaultFieldReaderMap</param>
                <mapFieldByTypeName hint="raw:AddFieldReaderByFieldTypeName">
                  <fieldReader fieldTypeName="checkbox" fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.CheckboxFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
                  <fieldReader fieldTypeName="date|datetime" fieldReaderType="Sitecore.Marketing.Search.FieldReaders.NullableDateFieldReader, Sitecore.Marketing.Search"/>
                  <fieldReader fieldTypeName="image" fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.ImageFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
                  <fieldReader fieldTypeName="single-line text|multi-line text|text|memo" fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.DefaultFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
                  <fieldReader fieldTypeName="integer" fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.NumericFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
                  <fieldReader fieldTypeName="number" fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.PrecisionNumericFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
                  <fieldReader fieldTypeName="html|rich text" fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.RichTextFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
                  <fieldReader fieldTypeName="multilist with search|treelist with search" fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.DelimitedListFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
                  <fieldReader fieldTypeName="checklist|multilist|treelist|treelistex|tree list" fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.MultiListFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
                  <fieldReader fieldTypeName="icon|droplist|grouped droplist" fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.DefaultFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
                  <fieldReader fieldTypeName="name lookup value list|name value list" fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.NameValueListFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
                  <fieldReader fieldTypeName="droplink|droptree|grouped droplink|tree|reference" fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.LookupFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
                  <fieldReader fieldTypeName="attachment|frame|rules|tracking|thumbnail" fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.NullFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
                  <fieldReader fieldTypeName="file|security|server file|template field source|link" fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.NullFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
                </mapFieldByTypeName>
              </fieldReaders>
              <indexFieldStorageValueFormatter type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Converters.SolrIndexFieldStorageValueFormatter, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                <converters hint="raw:AddConverter">
                  <converter typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldGuidValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" handlesType="System.Guid" />
                  <converter typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldIDValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" handlesType="Sitecore.Data.ID, Sitecore.Kernel" />
                  <converter typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldShortIDValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" handlesType="Sitecore.Data.ShortID, Sitecore.Kernel" />
                  <converter typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldUTCDateTimeValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" handlesType="System.DateTime" />
                  <converter typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldDateTimeOffsetValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" handlesType="System.DateTimeOffset" />
                  <converter typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldTimeSpanValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" handlesType="System.TimeSpan" />
                  <converter typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldSitecoreItemIDValueConvertor, Sitecore.ContentSearch" handlesType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemId, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                    <param type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldIDValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
                  </converter>
                  <converter typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Converters.SolrIndexFieldSitecoreItemUniqueIDValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" handlesType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemUniqueId, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                    <param type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldItemUriValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
                  </converter>
                  <converter typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldItemUriValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" handlesType="Sitecore.Data.ItemUri, Sitecore.Kernel" />
                  <converter typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldLanguageValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" handlesType="Sitecore.Globalization.Language, Sitecore.Kernel" />
                  <converter typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldCultureInfoValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" handlesType="System.Globalization.CultureInfo" />
                  <converter typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldVersionValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" handlesType="Sitecore.Data.Version, Sitecore.Kernel" />
                  <converter typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldDatabaseValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" handlesType="Sitecore.Data.Database, Sitecore.Kernel" />
                  <converter typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexableIdConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" handlesType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.IIndexableId, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
                  <converter typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexableUniqueIdConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" handlesType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.IIndexableUniqueId, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
                </converters>
              </indexFieldStorageValueFormatter>
              <indexDocumentPropertyMapper type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Mapping.SolrDocumentPropertyMapper, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                <objectFactory type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.DefaultDocumentMapperObjectFactory, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              </indexDocumentPropertyMapper>
             <documentBuilderType>Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrDocumentBuilder, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider</documentBuilderType>
              <defaultSearchSecurityOption ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSearchSecurityOption" />
            </extendedSolrIndexConfiguration>
          </indexConfigurations>
        </contentSearch>
      </sitecore>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: In your question you have unclosed comment for `<!-- FIELD TYPE MAPPING` which I believe may cause that half of your config is not read.

Comment: That was only a type in the question. I will update it now.

Answer (score 2):

`indexAllFields` should be inside `documentOptions` tag

```
<defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
 <documentOptions type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrDocumentBuilderOptions, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
   <indexAllFields>true</indexAllFields>
 </documentOptions>
</defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
```

You can check solr default index `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config` in this location `\App_Config\Sitecore\ContentSearch\`

Comment: I did added the document options after the field mapping. The fields are still not indexed.



<documentOptions type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrDocumentBuilderOptions, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" >
            <!-- GLOBALLY EXCLUDE TEMPLATES FROM BEING INDEXED
               This setting allows you to exclude items that are based on specific templates from the index.
            -->
   <indexAllFields>true</indexAllFields>

Comment: After adding documentOptions tag are you still getting this error "</documentOptions>"?

Comment: Not getting error. But the fields are not indexing. summary_t and other basic fields are missing from index.

Comment: is summary_t  field getting index in master index?

Comment: It is in the index now. But I am getting error in the sitecore search log

Comment: Can you share that error?

Comment: Solr Error : ["undefined field summary"] 
Query contains this (can't paste the whole query here)
summary:(res)
The field in Solr is summary_t but I think we don't need to append _t at the end. When I append _t and run the query in solr interface it seems to work. Why sitecore is not appending it by default?

Comment: For text field sitecore append '_t' automatically. You can see this setting in index file     <typeMatch typeName="text" type="System.String" fieldNameFormat="{0}_t" cultureFormat="_{1}" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" /> so while are getting result you need to "_t" which will be similar to solr index field

Comment: I can see the configuration. But why sitecore is not appending ‘_t’ while generating the search query?

Answer (score 0):

There is `documentOptions` node missing in your config. Should be:

```
<extendedSolrIndexConfiguration>
    <documentOptions type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrDocumentBuilderOptions, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
        <indexAllFields>true</indexAllFields>

        <exclude hint="list:AddExcludedTemplate">...</exclude>

        <exclude hint="list:AddExcludedField">...</exclude>

        <fields hint="raw:AddExcludedSpecialField">...</fields>

        <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">...</fields>
    </documentOptions>
</extendedSolrIndexConfiguration>
```